# Match a specific word if it contains an uppercase letter

Tags: regex, pcre, pcre2

What's the [PCRE2](https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/blob/master/README) regular expression syntax to match a specific word if and only if it contains at least one uppercase letter? I can currently match both conditions individually (`^foobar$` or `[A-Z]+`), but don't know how to combine as a compound conditional.
Expected results for testing "**foobar**":

```
✅ Foobar    ✅ fooBAR    ❌ foobar    ❌ Foobars   ❌ sFoobar
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @AndrejKesely - updated with PCRE2, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positive lookahead assertions `(?=...)` and local options `(?i:...)` can be used:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?i:foobar)$
```

Tests: https://regex101.com/r/JdQlaQ/1